# Delphi TEventHandler not assign

Tags: delphi, events

I have following simple DLL :

```
type
  TEventHandler = class
  public
    class procedure MenuClick(Sender: TObject);
  end;

class procedure TEventHandler.MenuClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(TMenuItem(Sender).Tag));
end;

procedure InjectPopupMenu(CallerForm: TForm; HostMenuItem: TMenuItem);
var
  SubMenu: TMenuItem;
  I: Integer;
begin
  for I := 1 to 20 do
  begin
    SubMenu := TMenuItem.Create(HostMenuItem);
    SubMenu.Caption := 'Test ' + IntToStr(I);
    SubMenu.Tag := I;
    SubMenu.OnClick := TEventHandler.MenuClick;
    HostMenuItem.Add(SubMenu);
  end;
end;

exports
  InjectPopupMenu;
```

and use it in an application this way :

```
type
  TInjectPopupMenu = procedure(CallerForm: TForm; HostMenuItem: TMenuItem);

procedure TForm1.LoadPopupMenuPlugin(CallerForm: TForm;
  HostMenuItem: TMenuItem);
var
  InjectPopupMenu: TInjectPopupMenu;
begin
  @InjectPopupMenu := GetProcAddress(FPopupMenuPlugin, 'InjectPopupMenu');
  InjectPopupMenu(CallerForm, HostMenuItem);
end;
```

Now i have 20 sub menu in my menu item and each one have an event handler for click operation that show the Tag property of theme, now my problem is all of the sub menu is work without any problem and show the value of Tag property of selected menu except item 2, when i click on menu item 2 nothing happens !

Any idea ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The obvious problem with this code is that you are mixing different instances of the VCL. Your DLL has one instance of the VCL, and your host executable has a different instance. So when you pass objects from one instance to the other, as you do, then you are breaking the rules.

On top of that, your code doesn't recognise that `TForm` in the DLL is a different class from `TForm` in the host. They might have the same names, but they are different instances. Likewise for `TMenuItem` and so on.

The bottom line here is that you cannot pass Delphi classes across module boundaries like this unless you are using runtime packages. Only by using runtime packages can you arrange for `TForm` to be the same class in both modules.

If you are not able to use runtime packages then you'll need to use a valid form of interop. The most obvious way to do this is by making use of interfaces. These are valid to pass across a module boundary.

Even then you've got a problem that is quite tricky to overcome. Consider your event handler:

```
class procedure TEventHandler.MenuClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(TMenuItem(Sender).Tag));
end;
```

This is declared in the DLL, but following the logic detailed above, the menu item would have been created by the host executable. In your code at the moment, that's not the case, but in order for any of this to work you need all the GUI to be part of the same instance of the VCL, that of the host executable.

So, how can you expect to do anything with `Sender` in the DLL since you cannot access it directly. You would have to treat `Sender` as an opaque pointer and call back into the host to be able to do anything with it. That's because only the host executable is allowed to call methods, cast it, test its type and so on.

So, whilst it is possible to implement all this without using packages, it makes life very complex.